# Close and reopen ssh connection without losing current process

Tags: linux, process, ssh

If I open an ssh connection and start a long-running process, is there any way to close the ssh connection, and not only keep the process running, but be able to later ssh back in again, and "reattach" the process to the terminal?

I am able to do the following:

```
Ctrl-z
bg
disown
```

And that lets me keep the process running after I leave my ssh session, but I am not able to "reown" the job later; is there a way to do this? The real-world scenario is that I'd like to start a process at work, drive home, then log back in and check on it/interact with it.

I know that `tmux` is able to handle things like this, but I am often forgetful, or I just don't know ahead of time what process will be long-running and what won't, so I don't always remember to start the process from within tmux.

Comment: No. not with ssh. to be able to "reattach", you'd need to run something like [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the remote end, and have you process running inside that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this. I used to use `screen` and that was a round about way of doing it. But check out `mosh`, built just for this:  http://mosh.mit.edu/